# Using SimpleInjector scopes in SpecFlow 3 life cycle hooks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, specflow, asp.net-core-2.1, simple-injector

I'm trying to setup my Specflow (V. 3.0.155 beta) tests in a .Net Core 2.1 Web API and I'm following a structure I've used in some previous .Net Framework Web API projects I've worked on to do so.

But I'm running into trouble when I try to resolve my dependencies, it seems as though I'm moving out of scope so when I try to resolve something, i.e. my test data context, I get the following error from SpecFlow:

> Message: SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The registered delegate
>   for type
>   ProjectNexusContext threw an exception. The ProjectNexusContext is
>   registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested
>   outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.   ---->
>   SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The ProjectNexusContext is
>   registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested
>   outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.

Stack trace:

> Result StackTrace:     at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
>   at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceTService    at
>   ProjectNexus.ApplicationContext.ResolveT in
>   C:\Users\dawes\source\repos\ProjectNexus\ProjectNexus\ApplicationContext.cs:line
>   18    at ProjectNexus.Engine.Specs.LifecycleTestHooks.AfterStep() in
>   C:\Users\dawes\source\repos\ProjectNexus\ProjectNexus.Engine.Specs\LifecycleTestHooks.cs:line
>   37    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) in
>   D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Bindings\BindingInvoker.cs:line 73    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker
>   invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType) in
>   D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line
>   246    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType
>   hookType) in
>   D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line
>   232    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager
>   contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) in
>   D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line
>   367    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.Step(StepDefinitionKeyword
>   stepDefinitionKeyword, String keyword, String text, String
>   multilineTextArg, Table tableArg) in
>   D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line
>   475    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.Given(String text, String
>   multilineTextArg, Table tableArg, String keyword) in
>   D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\TestRunner.cs:line 75    at
>   ProjectNexus.Engine.Specs.Tests.Client.Authentication.LogInFeature.FeatureBackground()
>   in
>   C:\Users\dawes\source\repos\ProjectNexus\ProjectNexus.Engine.Specs\Tests\Client\Authentication\Log
>   In.feature:line 7    at
>   ProjectNexus.Engine.Specs.Tests.Client.Authentication.LogInFeature.LogInWithAValidUsernameAndPassword()
>   in
>   C:\Users\dawes\source\repos\ProjectNexus\ProjectNexus.Engine.Specs\Tests\Client\Authentication\Log
>   In.feature:line 6
>   --ActivationException    at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1
>   registration)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration`1.GetInstance(Scope
>   scope)    at lambda_method(Closure )    at
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance() Result Message: 
>   SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The registered delegate for type
>   ProjectNexusContext threw an exception. The ProjectNexusContext is
>   registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested
>   outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.   ---->
>   SimpleInjector.ActivationException : The ProjectNexusContext is
>   registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested
>   outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope. Result
>   StandardOutput:    Given The following users are stored in the database 
>   --- table step argument ---   | Forneame | Surname | Username |   | John     | Smith   | js001    |
>   -> error: The registered delegate for type ProjectNexusContext threw an exception. The ProjectNexusContext is registered as 'Async Scoped'
>   lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an
>   active (Async Scoped) scope.

I'm using Simple Injector 4.4.2 and in my test project and I setup my container 
and register my instances in a static class method which is called in the BeforeTestRun SpecFlow life cycle hook.

Then in my BeforeScenario hook I'm beginning a new AsyncScopedLifestyle scope on said container which is to be used throughout for the given scenario. Next, In my AfterScenario hook I then dispose of this lifestyle. I've looked at the SimpleInjector documentation regarding this lifestyle and am aware that this exception is thrown when outside the context of an active scope but I cannot see why I'm outside the active context!

Upon inspecting the Scope in the BeforeStep hook, I can see that, although not disposed, the CurrentScope property in the ScopeManager is null so I'm clearly out of an active scope context.

This has never been an issue before and the code is exactly the same as in the aforementioned previous projects that go about using SimpleInjector in their test projects in exactly the same way. I even stepped through them and checked the scope in the BeforeStep hook and the CurrentScope in the ScopeManager was the scope so they're obviously not out of scope at that point.

I was hoping someone might see something I'm missing or have some suggestions as to how to go about resolving this.

I've included the code for my SpecFlow hooks and IoC Setup below:

**SpecFlow hooks:**

```
[Binding]
public class LifecycleTestHooks
{

[BeforeTestRun]
public static void BeforeTestRun()
{
    TestIocConfiguration.Configure();
}

[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    TestIocConfiguration.StartExecutionScope();
}

[BeforeStep]
public void BeforeStep()
{
    var projectDbContext = ApplicationContext.Resolve<ProjectNexusContext>();
    projectDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
}

[AfterStep]
public void AfterStep()
{
    var projectDbContext = ApplicationContext.Resolve<ProjectNexusContext>();
    if (projectDbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction != null)
    {
        try
        {
            projectDbContext.Database.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            projectDbContext.Database.RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
    }
    TestIocConfiguration.CheckExecutionScope();
}

[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    TestIocConfiguration.EndExecutionScope();
}
}
```

**IoC Setup**

```
 public class TestIocConfiguration
    {
        static Container container;

        public static void Configure()
        {
            container = ApplicationContext.Container;
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

            EngineInitialisation.Initialise();

            container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

            RegisterTestDatabaseContext();
            RegisterTestApplicationConfiguration();
            RegisterTestLdapConnectionService();
            RegisterTestContext();
        }

        private static void RegisterTestDatabaseContext()
        {
            var testContext =
                new ProjectNexusContext(new TestContextHelper().GetDbContextOptionsBuilder());
            testContext.Database.OpenConnection();
            testContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            container.Register<ProjectNexusContext>(() => testContext, Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }

        private static void RegisterTestLdapConnectionService()
        {
            container.Register<ILdapConnectionService, TestLdapConnectionService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }

        private static void RegisterTestApplicationConfiguration()
        {
            var appConfig = new ApplicationConfiguration
            {
                LdapHost = "",
                LdapPort = 0,
                ApplicationSecret = "TestSecret",
                TokenExpirationDays = 1
            };
            container.Register<ApplicationConfiguration>(() => appConfig, Lifestyle.Scoped);
        }

        private static void RegisterTestContext()
        {
            container.Register<TestContext>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        }

        public static Scope StartExecutionScope()
        {
            return AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container);
        }

        public static void EndExecutionScope()
        {
            Lifestyle.Scoped.GetCurrentScope(container)?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Application Context**

```
public class ApplicationContext
{
    public static readonly Container Container;
    public static readonly Mapper Mapper;

    static ApplicationContext()
    {
        Container = new Container();
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Container.GetInstance<T>();
    }

    public static Cast Resolve<T, Cast>()
        where Cast : T
        where T : class
    {
        return (Cast)Container.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception (and all its inner exceptions)

Comment: @Steven I've amended the question to include the requested details.

Comment: Is there any complete demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @TaoZhou due to the nature of this project, I'm unable to provide the exact code I'm using. However, I've created a separate test project you can run which recreates the issue and demonstrates exactly how I'm doing things and the issues I'm having. Here is a [link](https://github.com/dawesy9/SpecFlow3IocTestProject) to said project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before each spec you will need to create a new Container to be used as I don't think re-using will do what your expecting with the current set up.

You can add a method called `SetContainer` in your `ApplicationContext` like so:

```
public static void SetContainer(Container container)
{
    Container = container;
}
```

And then in your `BeforeScenario` hook you can run your IoC configuration, but new up a container and use your `SetContainer` method

**UPDATE**: It seems with Specflow 3-beta, the active scope gets disposed as soon as it leaves the test hook method (e.g. BeforeScenario)

For now you can register your instances with a singleton lifestyle, and use a new container for each test (like you can do with the suggestion I made above).

I tried identical code in Specflow 2.3.2 and it works fine, but breaks in Specflow 3-beta.

Comment: This answer makes me horny :)